# Having difficulty in finding the input string

Tags: assembly, x86-64, system, reverse-engineering

```
0x5555555553b1 <phase_5>        push   %rbx                                                                                                                           │
│   0x5555555553b2 <phase_5+1>      mov    %rdi,%rbx                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553b5 <phase_5+4>      callq  0x55555555560f <string_length>                                                                                                 │
│   0x5555555553ba <phase_5+9>      cmp    $0x6,%eax                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553bd <phase_5+12>     jne    0x5555555553f0 <phase_5+63>                                                                                                    │
│   0x5555555553bf <phase_5+14>     mov    %rbx,%rax                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553c2 <phase_5+17>     lea    0x6(%rbx),%rdi                                                                                                                 │
│   0x5555555553c6 <phase_5+21>     mov    $0x0,%ecx                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553cb <phase_5+26>     lea    0x150e(%rip),%rsi        # 0x5555555568e0 <array.3420>                                                                         │
│  >0x5555555553d2 <phase_5+33>     movzbl (%rax),%edx                                                                                                                    │
│   0x5555555553d5 <phase_5+36>     and    $0xf,%edx                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553d8 <phase_5+39>     add    (%rsi,%rdx,4),%ecx                                                                                                             │
│   0x5555555553db <phase_5+42>     add    $0x1,%rax                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553df <phase_5+46>     cmp    %rdi,%rax                                                                                                                      │
│   0x5555555553e2 <phase_5+49>     jne    0x5555555553d2 <phase_5+33>                                                                                                    │
│   0x5555555553e4 <phase_5+51>     cmp    $0x28,%ecx                                                                                                                     │
│   0x5555555553e7 <phase_5+54>     je     0x5555555553ee <phase_5+61>                                                                                                    │
│   0x5555555553e9 <phase_5+56>     callq  0x555555555856 <explode_bomb>                                                                                                  │
│   0x5555555553ee <phase_5+61>     pop    %rbx                                                                                                                           │
│   0x5555555553ef <phase_5+62>     retq                                                                                                                                  │
│   0x5555555553f0 <phase_5+63>     callq  0x555555555856 <explode_bomb>                                                                                                  │
│   0x5555555553f5 <phase_5+68>     jmp    0x5555555553bf <phase_5+14>
```

I have figured out that it needed six character input string and that it should add up to 0x28.But have no idea as how to get the required string.I know that it should be lower 4 bits of ASCII.

Any help is appreciated

Lookup table :

```
(gdb) x/16wd  0x5555555568e0
0x5555555568e0 <array.3420>:    2       10      6       1
0x5555555568f0 <array.3420+16>: 12      16      9       3
0x555555556900 <array.3420+32>: 4       7       14      5
0x555555556910 <array.3420+48>: 11      8       15      13
```

How should I interpret this table

Comment: The code is adding up a bunch of numbers from a lookup table located at `0x5555555568e0`, so I suggest you take a look there.

Comment: yup done that and im getting : (gdb) x/16wd  0x5555555568e0
0x5555555568e0 <array.3420>:    2       10      6       1
0x5555555568f0 <array.3420+16>: 12      16      9       3
0x555555556900 <array.3420+32>: 4       7       14      5
0x555555556910 <array.3420+48>: 11      8       15      13

Comment: How do i interpret this

Comment: Well, you need 6 values that add up to 40.

Comment: but how do i convert these values to characters for input

Comment: Nevermind t defused it. Thanks !!!